# why return statement does not return float?

Tags: c

I am new to programming and learning C from schildt's teach yourself C. I am trying to make a function that returns square. but when I input numbers with decimals it outputs as whole number. why does it do that?
my program :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int get_sqr(void);

void main()
{
    float x;
    x = get_sqr();
    printf("square : %f",x);
    return 0;
}

int get_sqr(void)
{
    float y;
    printf("enter a number : ");
    scanf("%f",&y);
    return y*y; /*returning the square result to assignment argument */
}
```

Comment: Because `int get_sqr(void);`

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting._

Comment: You said that the get_sqr function that take void parameter must return a int change `int get_sqr(void);` to `float get_sqr(void);`

Comment: @absinth your functions return an `int`, but it should return a `float`. In other words: `int get_sqr(void)` -> `float get_sqr(void)`

Comment: You do understand what the `int` means in `int get_sqr(void);`, right?

Comment: thank you m.nachury. such a foolish mistake got my head spinning this whole time :)

Comment: I get it now, return operator returns same type with which the function is declared.thank you all. or am I wrong ?

Comment: @absinth Yes, See my answer. You've declared a function returning `int` so even though the `return` statement is a `float` it gets truncated to an `int` to conform to the function prototype which is `int get_sqr(void)`.

Comment: PS: Schlidt's Teach Yourself C is a terrible terrible book. I'm not sure what the best modern books are but Herbert Schlidt is responsible for propagating some very nasty habits. Find an alternative. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 2):

It's because the return value of `get_sqr()` is `int`.
Although the value in the `return` statement is a `float` C implicitly converts that to an `int` because the function is declared returning an `int`:

```
int get_sqr(void)
```

Change that line to

```
float get_sqr(void)
```

and the full `float` value of `y*y` will be returned.